# Does smaller bulb increase the sensitivity of a liquid-in-glass thermometer? does a smaller flask increase the sensitivity?

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature

as for a thermometer, what's the difference between a bulb and a flask?
I have seen contradictory answers about how the size of a bulb affects the sensitivity. One says a a small size will be better in sensitivity, but others say the opposite is true.

Comment: Question is unclear and confusing and needs re editing both description and title. You have to specify if you mean a mercury based thermometer? Please use one question mark per title and also capitalization of first letter at the start of a sentence.

Comment: I always go for big bulb because heat loss by mercury is negligible even though the bulb contains more mercury or alcohol ;D

Answer (score 0):

A smaller bulb has smaller thermal mass.  It will more quickly come to thermal equilibrium with the environment, and it will affect the thing being measured less.

But the smaller bulb has less liquid inside.  That means for the same temperature rise, the top of the fluid will move a smaller distance and the reading will be less precise.

Given a long time to reach equilibrium and a large-enough system to measure, the large bulb will give a more precise measurement.  But for smaller systems (like a fluid in a flask), the equilibrium time and the changes the measurement inflicts on the system may require a smaller bulb.